# JAX RS Jersey Schema Validation

Tags: validation, rest, schema, jaxb, jax-rs

How to configure schema validation for JAX-RS RESTFul services?

We are using XSD to define the models, and JAXB to generate the java models.

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar question, it involves creating a MessageBodyReader: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service/3440388#3440388

Answer (score -1):

This is how it's done automatically in [ReXSL](http://www.rexsl.com): [XslResolver#addXsdValidatorToMarshaller()](http://trac.fazend.com/rexsl/browser/rexsl/trunk/rexsl/rexsl-core/src/main/java/com/rexsl/core/XslResolver.java?rev=1558&marks=238-291) (pay attention to the highlighted method). In a nutshell, you need to use `setSchema()` of your JAXB `Marshaller`.