# Bypassing JAX-WS SOAP overhead with JAX-RS/Jersey?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, wsdl

The only web services I've ever integrated with or used have been RESTful. I'm now trying to integrate with a 3rd party SOAP service and am awe-struck at how *seemingly* convoluted SOAP appears to be.

With REST, I use a JAX-RS client called [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) that makes hitting RESTful endpoints a piece a' cake. For instance, if a service is exposing a `POST` endpoint at `http://api.example.com/fizz` (say, for upserting `Fizz` objects), then in Jersey I might make a service client that looks like this (pseudo-code):

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
class Fizz {
    int type
    boolean derps
    String uid
}

class FizzClient {
    WebResource webResource = initAt("https://api.example.com")

    upsertFizz(Fizz fizz) {
        webResource.path("fizz").post(fizz)
    }
}
```

But Java-based SOAP clients *seem*, at first blush, to be fairly more complicated. If I understand the setup correctly, the general process is this:

1. Obtain an XML document called a `WSDL` from the service provider; this appears to be a language-agnostic description of all the available endpoints
2. Run a JDK tool called `wsimport` on the `WSDL` which actually generates Java source code, which implements JAX-WS APIs and actually represents my SOAP client
3. Import those generated source files into my project and use them

First off, if anything I have said about this process is incorrect, please begin by correcting me! Assuming I'm more or less correct, what I don't understand is: **why is this necessary if its all an HTTP conversation?** Why couldn't I achieve SOAP-based conversations with Jersey, and bypass all this source-generation boilerplate?

For instance, say the same endpoint exists, but is governed by SOAP:

```
class FizzClient {
    WebResource webResource = initAt("https://api.example.com")
    FizzSerializer serializer // I take Fizz instances and turn them into XML
    FizzDeserializer deserializer // I take XML and turn them into Fizz instances

    upsertFizz(Fizz fizz) {
        String xmlFizz = serializer.serialize(fizz)
        webResource.path("fizz").post(xmlFizz)
    }
}
```

If I understand SOAP correctly, its just a way of utilizing HTTP verbs and request/response entities to send app-specific messages around; it's an HTTP "conversation". So why couldn't I hijack a REST framework like Jersey to HTTP POST messages, and in doing so, bypass this SOAP overhead?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884295/soap-vs-rest-differences

Comment: Thanks @UtteshKumar (+1) - however I understand, in principle, the differences between SOAP and REST. I guess I'm just pointing out that Jersey can be used to send any type of entity, as any type of content, to any URL, using any HTTP verb...so why (**ever?**) use JAX-WS/SOAP if it can be mimicked with REST/Jersey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to attract opinion-based answers, but first, you should understand that

- [jax-rs](/questions/tagged/jax-rs) is much younger than [jax-ws](/questions/tagged/jax-ws) ([jax-ws](/questions/tagged/jax-ws) had a [final draft in 2006](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224), JAX-RS came out in [2008-9](https://jsr311.java.net/history.html)).
- RESTful webservices standard, for many purposes is quite amorphous - many businesses prefer the comfort of a contract in the form of a WSDL.
- Not to mention that JAX-WS, in concert with WS-I provides many other standards that govern security, message reliability and other enterprise-goodies (under the generic "WS-*" banner) that businesses care about. There's a hodge-podge of libraries that are attempting to get that kind of uniformity on to the [jax-rs](/questions/tagged/jax-rs) platform, but for now, [jax-ws](/questions/tagged/jax-ws)/WS-I is the industry standard

Comment: Thanks @kolossus (+1) - but are you saying that I *can't* coerce Jersey to honor the client-side of SOAP, or just that I *shouldn't*? Thanks again!

Comment: [You can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886653/jax-rs-jersey-schema-validation) @smeeb, it's just not built into the platform (at least, not that I know of)