# JAXB and Entity Class validation

Tags: validation, rest, jaxb, jaxb2

For a REST-Webservice i had to validate incoming  Data.
Is is possible to validate incoming data with an Entity Class and JAXB , instead of xsd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a link of how you could validate Data in a JAX-RS service using JAXB validation based on a schema:

- [Validate JAXBElement in JPA/JAX-RS Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service/3440388#3440388)

If you don't have an XML schema from your model, then you could use JAXB to generate one:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema

If you wanted to do validation without an XML schema you could use something like Bean Validation ([JSR-303](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303)).  With this you would still need to implement a custom `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter`.

Comment: It would be really cool to have JSR-303 validation annotation from the XML Schema.

Comment: It would be great, if teher is an Possibility to use my EntityClass and the JAXB Un-/Marshaller Class in combination. With XmlRootElement(name="rootelement") and @XmlElement(name="child") i have all the properties i need. How do i validate my Incoming data against the element naming ?

Comment: @RenHoek - You could use JAXB to generate the schema based on your mappings (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema).  Then you could set it on the Unmarshaller to do the validation.

Comment: okay, i am stucking... how is it possible to Overwrite the MessageBodyReader  in Jersey ? Has to be in the Service class for a ressource ? ....

Comment: @RenHoek - The following should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service/3440388#3440388

Comment: okay... i was to blind. i have to Implemented for the ResourceService ... Thanks a lot