# Java: Jersey (JAX-RS) and JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT with annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

Currently I have my Jersey (JAX-RS) Webservice return an JAXB annotated Object with a simple `@Produces("text/xml")` in my Webservice method. Unfortunately the output looks rather messy because its not formatted with breaks and spaces.

**Is there an annotation I can use like RESTeasy's @Formatted**

or

**how do I implement a marshaller, and where?**

Answer (score 4):

In Jersey, you can add an init parameter to its servlet:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Formatted</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: By now (Jersey 2.12) the flag has changed its name to jersey.config.xml.formatOutput . It can be found in the class MessageProperties

Answer (score 1):

There is probably such an annotation in Jersey, but if there isn't you could leverage the JAX-RS concept of a `MessageBodyWriter` and leverage the JAXB `Marshaller` directly.  Below is a link to an answer I gave where a `MessageBodyReader` was leveraged in order to set schema validation on a JAXB `Unmarshaller`:

- [Validate JAXBElement in JPA/JAX-RS Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service/3440388#3440388)

Comment: I am sorry but I somehow dont understand how to create my own JAXB Marshaller that will format my output.

Comment: As far as I see it I have to make my own MessageBodyWriter tat sets FEATURE_FORMATTED to true, but I cant grasp how to.