# RESTful WebService Schema Validation

Tags: web-services, rest

I was going through the Jersey doc and found that the marshalling and unmarshalling happens
automatically using the JAXB annotation @XmlRootElement. My question here is how to impose
the schema (xsd) validation before the unmarshalling  process to get rid of any xml request errors.Any example of how validation works would be really great.

Thanks,
sanvy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate JAXBElement in JPA/JAX-RS Web Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service)

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer to a similar question, it involves creating a MessageBodyReader:

- [Validate JAXBElement in JPA/JAX-RS Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service/3440388#3440388)