# JAX-RS: Validating JSON and XML (RESTEasy)

Tags: rest, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

**Tech Stack**: Java 1.6, JPA (Hibernate 3), Spring 3, Oracle 11g, JAX-RS (RESTEasy)

Hello,

I am writing few RESTful web-services.
I am using RESTEasy..

What I am not sure about is how can I validate the JSON \ XML request??
With SOAP it was easy and straight forward.

After searching, I could not find anything which clearly states what needs to be done.
I found a post ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service/3440388#3440388)) which mentioned about using MessageBodyReader, but I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this to work.

the post quoted in the question does answer this qustion.
what I was not sure was not to hook the reader to the code, but that is done automatically using the **@Provider** annotation.