# Jersey doesn't honour required=true

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have following class annotated with JAX-RS:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Blub {
  @XmlElement (required = true)
  private String author;
```

with getter/and setter. I am using this object as parameter to a method:

```
@Path("/createBlub")
@POST
public ReplyObject createBlub(Blub blub) {
    try {
        ...
        //process here
            return ReplyObject.success("blub", result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(e);
    }
}
```

I am expecting Jersey to throw an Exception if in the parameter blub object the field author is not set. However, Jersey doesn't seem to care for the required attribute. I remember that it worked in other projects, but don't see the difference.

I am using jersey 1.12 without anything else:

```
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>JerseyServletContainerAdmin</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

            <init-param>
                    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
                    <param-value>xxx.yyy.zzz.admin</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.DisableXmlSecurity
                    </param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
                    <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>JerseyServletContainerAdmin</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

thanks in advance

regards
Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey is using JAXB for marshaling and unmarshalling which just means [transforming the data into a Java object. If you want validation you have to do it yourself](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_3_3-Validation.html#Validation).

Proposed solutions for that include [creating a custom `MessageBodyReader` to add the validation on unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service/3440388#3440388) or creating a more reusable implementation by writing a custom `ContextResolver` as described in this post: [Jersey JAX-RS and JAXB Schema Validation.](http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.ro/2011/10/jersey-jax-rs-and-jaxb-schema.html)

[JSR303](http://java.dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-made-simple) support would have been ideal for this sort of thing (working nicely with JSON data) but looks like that will be [available only in 2.x](https://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/dev/archive/2010-11/message/5). It should be possible though to adapt the solution from the above post and use JSR303.

And if the implementation gets too complicated you can always let Jersey create the object and then first-thing-first call some validation method of yours on the object, which normally shouldn't be more than a one liner, something like:

```
@Path("/createBlub")
@POST
public ReplyObject createBlub(Blub blub) {
    ValidationUtils.<Blub>validate(blub);
    ...
```