# How to treat exception thrown by setter on JAXB automatic unmarshal from request body?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jaxb, jax-rs

I send the following JSON request body to my controller:

```
{"Game": {"url": "asd"}}
```

where `Game` is my model class, annotated with `@XmlRootElement` (and some JPA annotations which are not important in this context).

The controller:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{name}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createRow(
    @PathParam("name") String name, 
    Game gameData) throws Exception{

    Game.createRow(gameData); // + exception handling etc.
}
```

Now, I understood that when `Game gameData` parameter of the controller method is created, my setters from the model class are called. The setter that requires attention is:

```
public void setUrl(String url) throws Exception{
  String regex = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

  System.out.println("URL: " + url);
  if ( url == null || url.length() == 0) {
    throw new Exception("The url of the game is mandatory!");
  } else {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
    if (!matcher.matches()) { 
      throw new Exception("The url is invalid! Please check its syntax!");
    } else {
      this.url = url;
    }
  }
}
```

What happens is that, during the deserialization of the JSON string to the Game object, the `The url is invalid!` exception is thrown, but only in the console of `TomEE`. What I want to do is to send this error to the client.

If I use an exception which extends `WebApplicationException` instead of the generic Exception, then I get an exception in the client, but not the one about the validity of the url. Instead, after the deserialization, `gameData.url` is NULL, and when I try to create a Game instance with the data from `gameData`, the setter will be called like `gameToBeCreated.set(NULL)`, and I will get the exception `Url is mandatory`, when actually an URL was sent from the client, but with bad syntax. It was not NULL when sent from client.

So, can I somehow intercept the exceptions thrown when the **automatic** unmarshalling happens and forward them to the client?

Answer (score 5):

### Interception Exceptions with JAXB

A `ValidationEventHandler` is used to intercept the exceptions that occur during unmarshalling.  If you want to collect all the errors that occur you can use a `ValidationEventCollector`.

**Java Model**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Always throw an error");
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.util.ValidationEventCollector;

public class Demo {

    private static String XML = "<foo><bar>Hello World</bar></foo>";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(XML));

        ValidationEventCollector vec = new ValidationEventCollector();
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(vec);
        unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(XML));
        System.out.println(vec.getEvents().length);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
1
```

### Integrating with JAX-RS

**`MessageBodyReader`**

You could create an instance of `MessageBodyReader` where you can leverage a `ValidationEventHandler` during the unmarshal process.  Below is a link giving an example of how to implement a `MessageBodyReader`.

- [Validate JAXBElement in JPA/JAX-RS Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428273/validate-jaxbelement-in-jpa-jax-rs-web-service/3440388#3440388)

**`ContextResolver<Unmarshaller>`**

Slightly higher level, you could implement `ContextResolver<Unmarshaller>` and have the `Unmarshaller` returned have the appropriate `ValidationEventHandler` on it.  It would look something like the following:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler;

@Provider
public class UnmarshallerResolver implements ContextResolver<Unmarshaller> {

    @Context Providers providers;

    @Override
    public Unmarshaller getContext(Class<?> type) {
        try {
            ContextResolver<JAXBContext> resolver = providers.getContextResolver(JAXBContext.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
            JAXBContext jaxbContext;
            if(null == resolver || null == (jaxbContext = resolver.getContext(type))) {
                jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
            }
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new DefaultValidationEventHandler());
            return unmarshaller;
        } catch(JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is there another option which doesn't include the implementation of a `MessageBodyReader`? I would like to use the automatic unmarshalling and just send, somehow, the thrown exception to the client.

Comment: @SorinAdrianCarbunaru - Implementing `ContextResolver<Unmarshaller>` may work better for you.

Comment: we are using TomEE and, unfortunately, Apache CXF does not support `@Provider`... a colleague with more experience than me tried to register the provider programmatically and he failed...

Comment: RestEasy 3.0.7.FINAL does not understand ContextResolver<Unmarshaller>
See: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/3.0.7.Final/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory.java#ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProviderInstance%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.util.Map%2Cjava.lang.Integer%2Cboolean%29

The MessageBodyReader approach works though

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there isn't a built-in solution.

My solution (must be adopted to your code and can be improved (submit response-code), of course):

**Create an ErrorList class**

This class will serve to store the errors, which occure in the setters of the game model class

```
    import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

    public class ErrorList {

    private String errorString;
    private String errorObject; 

    public ErrorList() {
    }

    public ErrorList(String errorString, String errorObject) {
        this.setErrorString(errorString);
        this.setErrorObject(errorObject);
    }

    public String getErrorString() {
        return errorString;
    }

    public void setErrorString(String errorString) {
        this.errorString = errorString;
    }

    public String getErrorObject() {
        return errorObject;
    }

    public void setErrorObject(String errorObject) {
        this.errorObject = errorObject;
    }

    public Response sendError() {
        throw new WebApplicationException(
                Response.status(400)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .entity(this.getErrorString() + " caused by " + this.getErrorObject())
                .build());  
    }
}
```

**Add a new list property to the game model class**

```
    @XmlTransient
    private ArrayList<ErrorList> errorList = new ArrayList<ErrorList>();
```

**Now you can check for errors in your setters and add errors to the list**

```
    public void setUrl(String url) {        
      String regex = "\\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

      if (url == null || url.length() == 0) {
        // Create a new element for the errorlist with your explanations
        ErrorList error = new ErrorList("ERROR_PROPERTY","Game.url"); 
        // Add it to the errorList of the instance
        this.errorList.add(error);      
        return;
      }

      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
      if (!matcher.matches()) {
        // Create a new element for the errorlist with your explanations
        ErrorList error = new ErrorList("ERROR_PROPERTY","Game.url"); 
        // Add it to the errorList of the instance
        this.errorList.add(error);  
        return;
      }

      this.url = url;
    }
```

**Add a method to the game model class, that checks if the errorList is populated**

```
public static void checkErrorList(Game gameData) {
    if (gameData.errorList != null && !gameData.errorList.isEmpty()) {
        gameData.errorList.get(0).sendError();
    }       
}
```

**Finally**

Now you can add

```
    checkErrorList(yourGameInstance);
```

to your methods at the beginning, for example

```
    public static Response createRow(Game gameData) {
      checkErrorList(gameData);
      ...
    }
```

and whenever you setSomething, you should call it again, before you try to send the data to a db or so.

```
    public static Response createRow(Game gameData, String newUrl) {
      checkErrorList(gameData);
      ...
      gameData.setUrl(newUrl);
      checkErrorList(gameData);
    }
```

It's not as fancy as it would be with a build-in function, but at least it get's the job done.

And yes, I'm new to (JAVA/)JAXB.

The approach could be simplified by leaving out the ErrorList class and use a one-dimensional ArrayList inside of the game class.

Comment: I suppose this would work, but, as you said, it is not a "fancy" solution. I am still waiting for an answer related to the automatic unmarshalling. Either one which shows me how to solve the problem the way I want, or one which simply confirms that what I want is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing exceptions to perform flow control and validation logic of known possible outcomes is not recommended. Throwing an exception is akin to a goto statement in other languages, telling the flow control I want to automatically go here. Sounds like you could include the URL status/validation in the Response and call an isUrlValid method like this to accomplish what you need:

```
public void setUrl(String url){
      this.url = url;
}

public boolean isUrlValid(){
  String regex = "^(https?|ftp|file)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

  System.out.println("URL: " + this.url);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(this.url);
  return matcher.matches();
}

public boolean isUrlEmpty(){
  return this.url == null || this.url.length() == 0;
}
```

Response:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{name}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createRow(
    @PathParam("name") String name, 
    Game gameData){

  if(!gameData.isUrlEmpty() && gameDate.isUrlValid()){
      Game.createRow(gameData); 
  }

  String json = //convert Game entity to json or include error msgs in JSON
  return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

}

Comment: the issue would be that we want to keep the validations on the setters... we believe that it is a setter's duty to do the validations...

Comment: Seems like a lot of work and extra complication, though i guess we all have different beliefs :) Based on your example, if you continue down this path I would definitely create a specific exception class or use an existing specific exception rather than the generic exception class.

Comment: I have a custom exception extending `WebApplicationException`.Before posting this I was performing some experiments with both `Exception` and my custom exception and the last experiment was probably with `Exception`.