# XML Validation in RESTFul Web Service- Jersey 311

Tags: java, xml, validation, rest, jersey

I've developed a RESTful web service which can accept xml. I am going to create XSD for the input xml format.

Now, when client sends some invalid xml which is not as per schema, how should i validate it? The values are set in a bean by publisher and stored in a bean by consumer. Now, How do I validate it's schema ?

XML sample:

```
<xml>
 <one>1</one>
 <two>2</two>
 <a>
   <b/>
   <c/>
</a>
<b>
   <b/>
   <c/>
</b>
</xml>
```

I hope you understood my question, please clarify.

Comment: Using JAXB you can unmarshal XML from a String. Setting an XML Schema location will also validate the XML against this XML Schema.

Comment: See [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3428273/2587435)